# How to give column name dynamicaly in pandas assign

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataFrame with two columns

```
lst = [['James',15],['Michael',10]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns = ['name','val'])
```

I only want to use pandas assign function to do the bellow task

```
col = 'val'
df1 = df1.assign(col=lambda x: x.val+10)
```

Which gives me this output

```
      name  val  col
0    James   25   35
1  Michael   20   30
```

But i actually want this

```
      name  val
0    James   25
1  Michael   20
```

I want to pass the column name `val` in `col` variable

Comment: Is it on purpose that `col`  is missing ?

Comment: col = 'val' i just wanted to do the addition on column val. assign is taking col as a column name but i want it as a variable and pass val

Comment: @AjayChinni You are using `[15,10]` in initial `df1` so expected output would be `[25,20]` please update question accordingly.

Comment: @DishinHGoyani Thanks for understanding my question and even correcting it. Perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It accept `*kwargs` keyword argument. So you can make first dictionary and then unpack using `**`.

```
col = 'val'
df1 = df1.assign(**{col:lambda x: x.val+10})
df1
      name  val
0    James   25
1  Michael   20
```